# Issue with accessing a value from a table with jquery

Tags: php, jquery

Hey guys I am trying to get a specific name from a table.  Here is my code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#NotesAccessor").click(function () {
      var notes_name = $(this).document.getElementById("#user_table");
      alert(notes_name);
      run();
    });
});
```

Here is the above this is where I am trying to access the associated username with which table row was click with the #notesAccessor

Table:

```
 .........
    <td>
        $csvusername
    </td>
.........
    <td>
    ";
      if ($checkNotes[1] == 'No')
    {
        echo "None";
    }
    if ($checkNotes[1] == 'Yes')
    {
            echo "<a href='#' id='NotesAccessor'>Click to access</a>";
    }
    echo "
    </td>
........
```

My question is - how do I get the $csvusername of the associated `NotesAccessor` so I can then send this to a dialog in Jquery and open of the notes of that one person I need to get.

Hope this makes sense.

update:

here is full table:

```
<table class='results'>
    <tr class='firsttr' style='background:gray;'>
        <td>First Name</td>
        <td>Last Name</td>
        <td>Email</td>
        <td>Phone</td>
        <td>Username</td>
        <td>Password</td>
        <td>Status</td>
        <td>Combined Single Limit</td>
        <td>Bodily Injury Each Person</td>
        <td>Bodily Injury Each Accident</td>
        <td>Property Damage</td>
        <td>Address</td>
        <td>Notes</td>
        <td>#</td>
    </tr>"; $j = 0; while ($row = $sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) { $val = 1; $csvfirst
    = $row; $csvfirstname = $csvfirst['firstname']; $csvlastname = $csvfirst['lastname'];
    $csvemail = $csvfirst['email']; $csvphone = $csvfirst['phone']; $csvusername
    = $csvfirst['username']; $csvpassword= $csvfirst['password']; $csvstatus
    = $csvfirst['status']; $csvnotes = $csvfirst['notes']; $csl = $csvfirst['Combinedlimit'];
    $bodyinj = $csvfirst['bodyinjur']; $eachacc = $csvfirst['bodyinjureachacc'];
    $propertydmg = $csvfirst['propertydmg']; // Select the current employees
    address $psql = "SELECT MailingAdrs FROM insuranceverificationdisclaimer
    WHERE TraineeUsername =:user"; $psth= $DBH->prepare($psql); $psth->execute(array(':user'
    => $csvusername )); while ($prow = $psth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) { $pcheck
    = $prow; $address = $pcheck['MailingAdrs']; } if ($csvstatus != "No Longer
    Work Here" && $csvstatus == "Confirmed"){ //check to see if notes exist
    if (empty($csvnotes)) { $checkNotes = 0; } else { $checkNotes = 1; } $memberfirstnamearray[$j]
    = $csvfirstname; $memberlastnamearray[$j] = $csvlastname; $memberemailarray[$j]
    = $csvemail; $memberphonearray[$j] = $csvphone; $membercsl[$j] = $csl;
    $memberbodyinj[$j] = $bodyinj; $membereachacc[$j] = $eachacc; $memberpropertydmg[$j]
    = $propertydmg; $memberstatus[$j] = $csvstatus; $memberaddress[$j] = $address;
    $j++; $i++; echo "
    <tr>
        <td>$csvfirstname</td>
        <td>$csvlastname</td>
        <td>$csvemail</td>
        <td>$csvphone</td>
        <td class='user_table'>$csvusername</td>
        <td>$csvpassword</td>
        <td>$csvstatus</td>
        <td>$csl</td>
        <td>$bodyinj</td>
        <td>$eachacc</td>
        <td>$propertydmg</td>
        <td>$address</td>
        <td>"; if ($checkNotes == 0) { echo "None"; } if ($checkNotes == 1) { echo
            "<a href='#' id='NotesAccessor'>Click to access</a>"; } echo "</td>
        <td>$i</td>
    </tr>"; } }
</table>
```

Comment: when using [**getElementById**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/document.getElementById) you don't specify the `#` tag. That is specific to jQuery selectors. Not sure if that has to do with anything you are having issues with.

Comment: What is your logic for which TD is relevant? Is it the previous TD to the one containing the link,perhaps?

Comment: As JohnFx said, you need to be a little clearer on the exact `td` you need. Also, if you are planning of having multiple rows with that feature then remove the `id` of the anchor and replace with a `class` as duplicate identifiers will not work with jQuery and are invalid HTML. It would be much much better if you can post the resulting HTML output instead of the PhP code as will make it much clearer what structure you have and leaves less to assumptions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are mixing pure JavaScript with jQuery, you can solve it as follows.

First of all, you can put a class to identify the `<td>` with `$csvusername`, like `class='td_with_csvusername'` and then do this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".NotesAccessor").on("click", function () {
        var td = $(this).parent().parent().find(".td_with_csvusername");
        alert(td.html());
    });
});
```

Comment: @FrançoisWahl thank you, I'm still learning how to use this posting tool.

Comment: @EricMartins Hey this worked great...except when I try to access another one it does not seem to work.

Comment: The table that I have is populated by a search result in database so I will have hundreds or so results so everyone that has notes will have the #NotesAccessor so I need to be able to get the username of that particular one.  the notes link is in a <td> and is a sibling to the username I am trying to get.

Comment: You can't use an id for more than one element, instead, you can change it to a class, like this:

Comment: $(document).ready(function () {
      $(".NotesAccessor").click(function () {
        var td =   $(this).parent().parent().find(".td_with_csvusername");
        alert(td.html());
      });
    });

Comment: @EricMartins: +1 Nice suggestion on the class before OP had added full information.

Answer (score 1):

Posting the output HTML is better than the PhP version but I assume you have HTML similar to this:

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>UserName</td>
            <td><a href='#' id='NotesAccessor'>Click to access</a>"</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Then you can look for the previous sibling of the parent of the anchor by using jQuery's [**parent()**](http://api.jquery.com/parent/) and [**prev()**](http://api.jquery.com/prev/), similar to this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#NotesAccessor").click(function () {
        var notes_name = $(this).parent().prev().html();
        alert(notes_name);
        //run();
    });
});
```

---

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/uaCzr/) - Looking to the matching username column

---

If the above HTML is not like that then please post the exact output as it is important for knowing how to traverse to the matching `td` in the same `tr` when you click the anchor. Assuming that is what you are trying to achieve.

**Edit**

Only seen your update now. I know you already have a solution but for completeness I have added to this answer anyway in case it is useful to future users.

In your sample code you already have class on the user-name cell `user_table`. You can use that to target instead then. Also, given you said you will have several rows with the `#NoteAccessor`, you should change the `id="NoteAccessor"` to `class="NoteAccessor"` as ids have to be unique or it is invalid HTML. In addition jQuery only returns the first element with a matched id.

The script which you end up with is straight forward then using `parent()` as before but now you can also use [**prevAll()**](http://api.jquery.com/prevall/) specifying the class selector:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    // using class ".NotesAccessor" instead of id "#NotesAccessor" 
    // as element is repeated in each tr
    $(".NotesAccessor").click(function () {
        var notes_name = $(this).parent().prevAll('.user_table').html();
        alert(notes_name);
    });
});
```

---

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/bMkmD/) - Using `parent()` and `prevAll('.user_table')`

---

Comment: @DavidBiga: I only seen your update now. I know you already have the solution but I edited my answer for completeness anyway in case it can help future users as well.